# Целесообразно ли упрощать данные перед подачей на вход нейросети

Tags: нейронные-сети

Целесообразно обрабатывать изображение вейвлет преобразованием перед подачей его на вход нейросети? Чтобы нс было легче классифицировать изображения.
Типа с помощью вейвлет преобразования находить признаки.

Comment: Это вопрос. ("У меня проблемы с интонацией?")

Comment: Я тоже не понял где в этом потоке предложений вопрос

Comment: Сделайте и так и так, и напишите потом, что оказалось эффективнее, с примерами кода.

Answer (score 1):

Как и любое упрощение исходных данных, контрпродуктивно пытаться комбинировать с нейросетями. Да, трафик памяти уменьшится, но это повлияет на качество обучения в разы - возможно, просто не будет учиться на упрощенных данных. Чем меньше посредников между информацией и программой обучения нейросети, тем лучше!

```
def auto_canny(arr, mat, sigma=0.33):
    v = np.median(arr)
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
    edged = cv2.Canny(mat, lower, upper)
    return edged

...

with mss.mss() as sct:

    while True:

        frame = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))

        gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray_image = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray_image, 25, 25, cv2.BORDER_WRAP)
        gray_image = auto_canny(frame, gray_image)

        frame = cv2.cvtColor(gray_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(gray_image, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416), swapRB=False, crop=True)
```

На практике был случай, делал программу, которая применяет canny фильтр на изображении, подаваемом нейросети. В теории, это должно было ускорить программу на порядок, так как вместо RGBA (32 бита), на вход подавалось по одному биту на пиксель. В результате это работало, но совсем плохо - пришлось отказаться от данного метода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно так выглядела синтетическая выборка для обучения - генерировалась автоматически и позволяла учить нейросеть на распознавание искомого контура на любом фоне. В основе реализации генератора фонового шума лежала функция геометрического преобразования [warpPolar](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga49481ab24fdaa0ffa4d3e63d14c0d5e4) из OpenCV.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот только стоило нам попытаться обучить классификатор ДВУХ контуров, используя этот принцип, мы потерпели фиаско. Кроме того, на надпись победа из той же Dota2 это уже не сработает - буквы уже и выборка будет совсем неоднозначной. Не наступайте на эти грабли, на мой взгляд, лучше "клеить" выборку из готовых данных, чем пытаться её "генерировать". Посмотреть, как это работает, можно [тут](https://youtu.be/FPEv_ulSMDE).

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос слишком глобален. Что за нейросеть? Какую задачу вы собрались решать? И почему именно вейвлет-преобразование, а не - например преобразование Фурье?

Общий ответ такой - любое преобразование исходных данных, а тем более преобразование, сокращающие объем описания данных (коим и является вейвлет-преобразование) всегда (!!!) приводит к потере информации. Как следствие - к потери точности построенного классификатора (например - нейронной сети). Однако может сокращать время работы вашего алгоритма. (Не путайте сокращение времени с "легкостью"). Поэтому в каждом случае отвечать на вопрос - надо или нет делать преобразование данных - это вопрос поиска компромисса между обозначенными характеристиками и должно решаться исключительно исходя из анализа самой задачи.